# How to read from specific sheet in excel by name

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have excel that contains 4 sheets (Cars,Models,Customers,Contact) i have this code below. 
I need to read from specific sheet in the excel (Tab), how to do this ? I am using Microsoft office Interop excel

```
        string Mysheet = @"C:\MSFT Site Account Updates_May 2015.xlsx";
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbooks books = excelApp.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook sheets = books.Open(Mysheet);

        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            string Name = ((excelApp.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range).Value);
            string SiteUrl = ((excelApp.Cells[i, 4] as Excel.Range).Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Account created");

        }
```

Thank you all

Comment: What currently happens? error?

Comment: Your `Mysheet` variable doesn't hold a sheet name. Maybe `Mybook` would be a better name. `sheets.Sheets("Cars")` will get a specific sheet by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var workbook = books.Open(Mysheet);
var worksheet = (Worksheet) workbook.Sheets["Customers"];

Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Cells[2, 2]); // for example...
```

Comment: This is a newer way to get sheets by name. The older one is get_item(...) which looks very old.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `Worksheet` for the sheet you want to read data from.  To get range `A1` from `Cars`, for example:

```
var app = new Application();
Workbooks workbooks = app.Workbooks;
Workbook workbook = workbooks.Open(@"C:\MSFT Site Account Updates_May 2015.xlsx");

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets["Cars"];

Range range = sheet.Range["A1"];
```